# hpux: how much memory process eating?

Tags: ram, hp-ux

I have found on web those two command line to see top 10 cpu and ram eating process

ram

```
echo " SZ PID RUSER COMMAND";UNIX95= ps -ef -o 'sz pid ruser args' |sort -nr|head -10
```

cpu

```
 echo " SZ PID RUSER COMMAND";UNIX95= ps -ef -o 'sz pid ruser args' |sort -nr|head -10
```

Someone know a command line to see how much mb of ram is consuming the top 10 process?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found in a very good script

http://www.cfg2html.com/

```
 echo "VSZ(KB)   PID RUSER   CPU    TIME  COMMAND"  UNIX95= ps -e -o 'vsz pid ruser cpu time args' |sort -nr|head -25
```